# Have the text from a text box print to the screen

Tags: javascript, button

```
<html>
<script>
var x= document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML;

function go(){
document.write(x);
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myText" size="1" value="" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="button" onclick="go()"/>
</body>
```

I am having trouble getting the text from my text box to print to the screen. I also don't want the button to disapear when the text is printed to the screen

Comment: _"I also don't want the button to disapear"_. Then don't use `document.write` that way.

Comment: then how should i do it then.

Comment: Where do you want the text from the input field to display when clicking the button? Do you have a target element it should show up in?

Comment: preferable in a text area below it. no i don't have a target area

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uKwCU/?

Comment: yea. i would also like to be able to click the button again and it would print the new info on a new line in the text box without erasing the info that was there before.

Answer (score 2):

To give some explanation to what is happening:

using [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) after the document has loaded calls [document.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.open) automatically which, "If a document exists in the target, this method clears it (see the example)."

To get around this for your use case you can just append a [textNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) or an element to the page where ever you would like it to go.

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="myText" size="1" value="" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="button" onclick="go()"/>
</body>
```

assuming this markup you can do something like this to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) it to the end of the page.

```
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
function go() {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myText.value));
}
```

as a side note: you should have a container (div element maybe) with an ID value that you can append these into instead of the body. It will give you more control if you ever want to work with the nodes in the future. I would also urge you to not use inline event listeners.

Answer (score -1):

You have to have a "target". If you don't have one - create it on the fly, for example SPAN:

```
function go(){
    var sp =  document.createElement('span')
    sp.innerHTML = document.getElementById('myText').value;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(sp);
}
```

btw, text input elements don't have `.innerHTML` they have `.value`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PKFG8/

*UPDATE*

This slightly updated function prints every new input on a new line, also as an added convenience clears user input and refocus on it after every click:

```
function go(){
    var txt = document.getElementById('myText');

    var sp =  document.createElement('div')
    sp.innerHTML = txt.value;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(sp);
    txt.value = '';
    txt.focus();
}
```

Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/PKFG8/2/

Comment: Can you please define - not working? Any errors? It's working in the demos which are based on your code. Please make sure you copy  the code correctly.

Comment: "Would the real downvoter please stand up?" and kindly explain the downvote?